# WEBSQL simple insert into populated table

Tags: mysql, sql

Can't seem to figure out why this simple statement doesn't work

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM scan");
```

It works correctly if the table history is empty which is not of much use but if the table history has any data then it does not carry out the insert I must do:

```
tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM history", []);
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM scan");
```

Any ideas? Cheers

Edit:

Structures are the same:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scan(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, sunum TEXT, binnum TEXT, userid TEXT, added_on DATETIME, upload_on DATETIME)");
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history(ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, sunum TEXT, binnum TEXT, userid TEXT, added_on DATETIME, upload_on DATETIME)");
```

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: do `scan` and `history` tables have the same number and type of columns ?

Comment: What are the column structures of the two tables?  What constraints do you have in the `History` table?

Comment: They are both the exact same and no error message, like I said it just only works if the table history is empty and then it will insert the data from scan into history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to insert a duplicate primary key value into the `History` table.  From your structure, they both have `ID` listed as a `PRIMARY KEY`, which cannot contain duplicate values.

Try specifying all columns except for that key:

```
INSERT INTO History
            (sunum, binnum, userid, added_on, upload_on)
SELECT      sunum, binnum, userid, added_on, upload_on
FROM        Scan
```

Though, looking at the structure, the `ID` values aren't auto-incremented.  If you don't care what the `ID` is, you can declare the `ID` column as: `ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.

If you need to pull the `ID` over from the other table, you'll have to do an upsert or merge into that table.